# How to pause the code until I want? [something like Thread.Sleep(int);]

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I think the best way to make my point is to give you these examples:

```
Console.ReadLine(); 
Process.WaitForExit();
```

These functions will pause the application (without freezing the UI).

I need something like this.

In fact, I am writing something like `ReadLine()` but in `windows forms applications`.
When you call this method, it should be waited until the user press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Is your question that you want to block a winforms app until the user presses Enter? That sounds like rather unusual UI.

Comment: You are incorrect about how those methods work. If you called them on a WinForms UI thread, they *would* lock your application.

Comment: Try using ShowDialog() instead of Show() on your form.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? (I am amazed by the people who are able to answer this without knowing what you are trying to achieve)

Comment: +1 for Erno - I'm confused as well. Within an event-handler, it would seem that a modal input dialog would do, as suggested by interationx.

Comment: I understand that you are confused because it's impossible to both pause the code and receive the key events. sorry for that. now i got my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console apps don't have a UI so there's nothing for WaitForExit() to freeze. In a console app the chrome (title bar and window buttons) are handled by the system. In a WinForms app those things aren't painted until you pass the NC_PAINT events to the default handler. If your main message loop is sleeping then your chrome doesn't get painted.

A WinForms app doesn't close automatically so there should be no reason to call something like WaitForExit(). Instead you explicitly tell the app when to close - say when the user presses escape or something.

Comment: you pointed to a the thing that i did not attend, i always call these methods on console application, after your comment i tested it on Windows Forms and then the result was the application stops, no key press can be received by the events. so i should completely forget this matter :) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can create a thread which does a wait on an [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx), the UI thread should continue and accept input which signals the event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [backGroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which simply checks for cancellation and waits some time using Thread.Sleep(100) for example.

The other way is to create own thread and control all checks and callbacks yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Task logManager = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {   /* Your code */ }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

or even

```
Task screenshotManager; 

     private void StartScreenshotManager()
            {
                screenshotManager = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ScreenshotManagerJob(); }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
                screenshotManager.ContinueWith((t) => { ScreenshotManagerUpdateUI(); }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            }

            private void ScreenshotManagerUpdateUI()
            {
                // ... UI update work here ... 
            }

            private void ScreenshotManagerJob()
            {
             // your code
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you don't need to halt the execution at all in Windows Forms application.

Windows Forms applications usually require a much more consistent architecture. If you need some code to proceed after the user input, you should not be halting a function execution. In contrast, open a dialog (or provide any other mean for the user to do the required input) and just wait for him to "interact with it". Interaction should raise C# `event`s that will be processed by an logical class instance that knows how to do it and is subscribed to them.